# I am getting Run-time error '94': Invalid Use of Null

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have my code below in order to see if a user creates a 4 digit pin, if they don't fill a pin then the pin will be set up as and empty string. No big deal.

I am testing this in the `if` statement below, but it is returning an invalid use of null exception:

```
Dim U As String
If Me.txtUnlock = Null Then
U = 0
Else
U = Me.txtUnlock
End If
If IsNumeric(U) = False Then
MsgBox "Unlock pin only accepts numbers only.", , "Retail unlock"
Me.txtUnlock = Null
Me.txtUnlock.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
If Len(U) <> 4 Then
MsgBox "Retail unlock must be four digits long.", , "Retail unlock"
Me.txtUnlock.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
```

Then I check if the pin is empty below:

```
 If IsNull(Me.txtUnlock) Then
    check = check + 1
    UL = ""
    Else
    UL = Me.txtUnlock
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this streamlined code using [NZ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa172237(v%3Doffice.11)) function:

```
Dim U As String
U = NZ(Me.txtUnlock,0)

Dim fail as Boolean
If Not IsNumeric(U) Then
    MsgBox "Unlock pin only accepts numbers only.", , "Retail unlock"
    fail = true
ElseIf Len(U) <> 4 Then
    MsgBox "Retail unlock must be four digits long.", , "Retail unlock"
    fail = true
End If

If fail then
    With Me.txtUnlock 
        .value = vbNullString
        .SetFocus
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Sorry I began writing a comment and clicked enter which saved it. What if I don't want it to return a 0. For some reason when it returns a zero it registers as a numeric value and keeps showing "Retail unlock must be 4 digits long.

Comment: @Cookies  add a condition for 0 as your first condtion  `If u = 0 Then ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
If Me.txtUnlock = Null Then
```

That you can't do. Try with:

```
If IsNull(Me!txtUnlock.Value) Then
```